# Twitter Login Won't Save In App Inventor

Tags: twitter, app-inventor

I'm making an android app that lets you login with your twitter account; the problem is that whenever you close the app, then open it (after signing in), you have to sign in again. Anyway users can stay logged in across multiple sessions?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

try my Twitter tutorial [here](https://puravidaapps.com/twitter.php) to see how to do it...